# VS code python extension

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed Microsoft python environment extension but it doesn't work and environment commnads are also not found in command palette.

[image]

Comment: Is the extension enabled (it should show you when you go to the extension under Marketplace). Did you try with a restart of vscode?

Comment: unfortunately it cant be enabled (turned off). restarted several times.

Comment: Maybe you should install python on your machine is separately from visual studio code, did you try that?

Comment: already installed. It used to be ok, but suddenly smth happened and this problem occured.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by clearing C:\Users**User**.vscode\extensions folders and reinstalling those extensions again.